Managed Identity for Blob-Triggered Azure Function: "No such host is known"
I am getting the following errors in my Blob Triggered Azure Function App:
Azure.Core: No such host is known. (examplestorage.blob.core.windows.net:443). System.Net.Http: No such host is known. (examplestorage.blob.core.windows.net:443). System.Net.Sockets: No such host is known.

We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. Refresh the page to try again. 

I have an Azure Function app which is Blob triggered:
[Function("ExampleFunction")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("%BlobPath%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlob, string name)

Previously I was using a connection string to connect to the Storage Account, however I want to update this to Managed Identity. I have followed this tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections
I have added the following attributes in Environment Variables:
AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName = examplestorage
AzureWebJobsStorage__blobServiceUri = https://examplestorage.blob.core.windows.net
AzureWebJobsStorage__credential = managedidentity
AzureWebJobsStorage__queueServiceUri = https://examplestorage.queue.core.windows.net

Instead of Connection = AzureWebJobsStorage, I have also tried using something like Connection = BlobTriggerConnection, then adding the following Environment Variables:
BlobTriggerConnection__blobServiceUri = https://examplestorage.blob.core.windows.net
BlobTriggerConnection__credential = managedidentity
BlobTriggerConnection__queueServiceUri = https://examplestorage.queue.core.windows.net

However this did not work for me either.
I am using a dedicated App Service Plan (ASP): Premium v3 P2V3
(I have seen it does not work with consumption or elastic premium plans)
I am also using the following:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="6.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.5.0" />

I have granted the following role assignments to the Function App to the Storage Account:
Storage Account Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Queue Data Contributor

I have also seen that it does not work with the connection strings:
WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE

My function app did have these app settings, and according to this discussion here, once the settings have been set there isn't a way to use Managed Identity. So, I have also tried re-deploying the Function App and ensured these variables were not ever present. However I still get the same error as I am getting in the original function app.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/use-managed-identity-instead-of-azurewebjobsstorage-to-connect-a/ba-p/3657606

managed identity will work only in azure not in local, if you are using userassigned identity you need to add the identity in function. you need to assign these roles based on the triggers or binding you are using. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections:~:text=Example%20built%2Din%20roles

Not using this locally, I am using this on a deployed Function app on an app service plan. Also using system-assigned identity of the Function app, no user-assigned identities

There was a very small typo in the storage account name. This has been fixed.
